# How to filter hyperlink cells in swt tableviewer

Tags: filter, hyperlink, swt, tableviewer

I have a problem i can't solve and I have spent a lot of time. I have a table and I have a column with hyperlinks. I have some filters added to the table and when I activate one of those filters, the hyperlink column doesn't refresh correctly. The code I implemented is showing above. This is an example you can copy&paste, run & reproduce the bug:

The Table class:

```java
package borrar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.events.HyperlinkAdapter;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.events.HyperlinkEvent;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink;

public class Example {

    private static TableViewer tViewer = null;
    private static Table tblTrades = null;
    private static Text txtTicker;
    public static TickerFilter2 tickerFilter = new TickerFilter2();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        Label lblTicker = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        lblTicker.setText("Search: ");
        txtTicker = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
        txtTicker.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        txtTicker.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                tickerFilter.setSearchText(txtTicker.getText());
                tViewer.refresh();
            }
        });
        tViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.CENTER);
        String[] titles = { "Ticker", "Hyperlinks" };
        createColumns(titles);
        tblTrades = tViewer.getTable();
        tViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        List<DataTable> dt = Arrays.asList(new DataTable("AAA", "ImagePath"), new DataTable("ABBBBBB", "ImagePath"),
                new DataTable("BBBBBBB", "ImagePath"));
        tViewer.setInput(dt);
        tblTrades.setHeaderVisible(true);
        tViewer.addFilter(tickerFilter);

        shell.open();
        shell.pack();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createColumns(String[] titles) {
        TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], 70);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                DataTable op = (DataTable) element;
                if (op.getTicker() != null) {
                    return op.getTicker();
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        });
        col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], 80);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            Map<Object, Hyperlink> hyperlinks = new HashMap<Object, Hyperlink>();

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
                final Hyperlink hyperlink;
                if (hyperlinks.containsKey(cell.getElement()) && !hyperlinks.get(cell.getElement()).isDisposed()) {
                    hyperlink = hyperlinks.get(cell.getElement());
                } else {
                    hyperlink = new Hyperlink((Composite) (cell.getViewerRow().getControl()), SWT.NONE);
                    if (cell.getElement() instanceof DataTable) {
                        DataTable trade = (DataTable) cell.getElement();
                        if (trade.getPath() != null && !trade.getPath().equals("")) {
                            hyperlink.setText(trade.getPath() + "-" + trade.getTicker());
                            hyperlink.setHref(trade.getPath());
                        }
                    }
                    hyperlink.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter() {
                        public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                            org.eclipse.swt.program.Program.launch(hyperlink.getHref().toString());
                        }
                    });
                    hyperlinks.put(cell.getElement(), hyperlink);
                }
                TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
                editor.grabHorizontal = true;
                editor.grabVertical = true;
                editor.setEditor(hyperlink, item, cell.getColumnIndex());
                editor.layout();
            }
        });
    }

    private static TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound) {
        final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tViewer, SWT.CENTER);
        final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
        column.setText(title);
        column.setWidth(bound);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        return viewerColumn;
    }

    public void refreshTable() {
        tViewer.refresh();
    }
}
```

My filter class:

```java
package borrar;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerFilter;

public class TickerFilter2 extends ViewerFilter {
    private String searchString;

    public void setSearchText(String s) {
        // ensure that the value can be used for matching
        this.searchString = ".*" + s + ".*";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
        if (searchString == null || searchString.length() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        DataTable trade = (DataTable) element;
        if (trade.getTicker().matches(searchString)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The data table object:

```java
package borrar;

public class DataTable {

    String ticker;
    String path;

    public DataTable(String ticker, String path) {
        super();
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }

    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

If you put in the search field a "z" or "l" for example, you can see that the hyperlink column does not filter.

The filter class filters data correctly but the hyperlinks column doesn't filter fine.

Here you have an image with the bad result:
[image: Here you have an image with the bad result]

Comment: There is far too much code here, please cut it down to a [mre]. You also haven't really explained what the filtering is supposed to do and exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response greg-449. I uploaded an image with the error. You can see the hyperlinks columns (Open Im...) doesn't filters fine.

Comment: @AaronPalazon That's not a minimal, reproducible example. The problem isn't that there's too little code that the problem can't be identified, but that there is too much code. Please remove parts of your code that aren't necessary to solve the problem (do we really need how the code determines which items to put in the list or would sample values for the list be sufficient?).  Also, [please post the table, not an image of the table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I have edited the example so you can copy & paste & and you can reproduce the bug. Than you all for all your help.

Comment: I think the basic problem is that TableViewer doesn't know anything about the TableEditor controls you use so it can't do anything about them when filtering. Using `EditingSupport` would be preferable (but you may have to do things somewhat differently)

Comment: @greg-449, can you post an example with editing support? I will do whatever I must do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TableViewer doesn't really know about the TableEditor code so it doesn't deal with them when filtering.

You could perhaps use the `EditingSupport` code. The following code defines a cell editor which does an action as soon as you click on the column cell.

For the column definition replace your code with something like:

```java
   col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getText(final Object element) {
          // Whatever you want for the cell text here
          final DataTable op = (DataTable) element;
          return op.getPath();
       }
    });

    col.setEditingSupport(new HyperlinkEditingSupport(tViewer));
```

The editing support class:

```java
public class HyperlinkEditingSupport extends EditingSupport
{
  private final HyperlinkCellEditor _editor;

  public HyperlinkEditingSupport(final TableViewer viewer)
  {
    super(viewer);

    _editor = new HyperlinkCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
  }

  @Override
  protected CellEditor getCellEditor(final Object element)
  {
    return _editor;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean canEdit(final Object element)
  {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getValue(final Object element)
  {
    // Return the value you want launched
    return ((DataTable)element).getPath();
  }

  @Override
  protected void setValue(final Object element, final Object value)
  {
    // no action
  }
}
```

And the `CellEditor`. This is a bit odd because we are just going to launch as soon as the editor is invoked so we don't really need a separate editor:

```java
public class HyperlinkCellEditor extends CellEditor
{
  public HyperlinkCellEditor(final Composite parent)
  {
    super(parent);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createControl(final Composite parent)
  {
    return new Composite(parent, SWT.None);
  }

  @Override
  protected Object doGetValue()
  {
    return new Object[0];
  }

  @Override
  protected void doSetFocus()
  {
    // no action
  }

  @Override
  protected void doSetValue(final Object value)
  {
    final String path = (String)value;

    // TODO Open the link
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @greg-449!!! You're my hero!! Last night I was developing a workaround and I was stucked because the listener opens the image two times. With this solution I have made it!!! Hundreds of millions of thanks!! I have a solution with a Styled Cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @greg-449 solution to show a link appearance in the cell only modifying the LabelProvider:

```
col.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            DataTable op = (DataTable) cell.getItem().getData();
            StyledString ss = new StyledString();
            StyleRange sr = new StyleRange(0, 80, Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE), null);
            sr.underline = true;
            ss.append(op.getPath(), StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
            cell.setText("Open Image");
            StyleRange[] range = { sr };
            cell.setStyleRanges(range);
        }
    });
    col.setEditingSupport(new HyperlinkEditingSupport(tViewer));
```